# Atributos mais Importantes no Random Forest Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning

Boa Tarde galera, gostaria de saber se tem como retornar um percentual de cada atributo utilizado no treino do Random Forest Classifier, para mostrar quais atributos são os mais determinísticos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ler a documentação sempre é um bom primeiro passo.

De qualquer forma, do
[manual](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html):

*feature_importances_ : array of shape = [n_features]

The feature importances (the higher, the more important the feature).*

Quem em uma tradução livre:

*importancia_das_variaveis_ : vetor com forma = [numero_de_atributos]
A importância das variáveis (quanto maior maior a importância da variável).*

Só para deixar extremamente claro, você vai inicializar o seu modelo (1),
treiná-lo (2) e depois obter uma importância de variáveis:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf = RandomForestClassifier()      # (1)
clf.fit(x, y)                       # (2)
print(clf.feature_importances_)     # (3)
```

Comment: Nada a ver com isso mas salvou minha vida em uma tradução, obrigada

Answer (score 1):

[Esse paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04938) propõe uma metodologia para analisar as predições desse tipo de algoritmo. Felizmente existe [esse projeto em python](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) que implementa a metodologia.

[Neste link](https://marcotcr.github.io/lime/tutorials/Tutorial%20-%20continuous%20and%20categorical%20features.html) tem um tutorial de uso exatamente com o RandomForest. Estou copiando o código abaixo para não correr o risco do link parar de funcionar.

```
import sklearn
import sklearn.datasets
import sklearn.ensemble
import numpy as np
import lime
import lime.lime_tabular
from __future__ import print_function
np.random.seed(1)

# treinar algoritmo 
iris = sklearn.datasets.load_iris()
train, test, labels_train, labels_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target, train_size=0.80)
rf = sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500)
rf.fit(train, labels_train)

# explicar as predições
explainer = lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(train, feature_names=iris.feature_names, class_names=iris.target_names, discretize_continuous=True)

i = np.random.randint(0, test.shape[0])
exp = explainer.explain_instance(test[i], rf.predict_proba, num_features=2, top_labels=1)
```